robotframework_ls didn't detect local keywords with coc nvim
I'm using neovim with coc extension.
I add the robotframework_ls server for lsp.
My project is stored in the following directory:
/home/jchabrol/personaltools/robot
with the following tree:
keywords (with all .resource keywords)
tests (with all .robot test file)
My coc-settings.json is like this:
{
  "languageserver": {
    "robotframework_ls": {
        "command": "robotframework_ls",
        "filetypes": ["robot"],
        "settings": {
          "robot.lint.robocop.enabled":true,
          "robot.pythonpath":["~/robot",
            "${workspaceFolder}/robot"
          ]
        }
    }
  }
}

When I open a test .robot file the coc or lsp server didn't find local keywork
or

I try different configuration without any results.

The draft guess is that there is an issue with path importing for resource if you use relative paths.
The relative path to the resource file is relative to the test location.
Then, your relative-style import path could look like
Resource   ../../keywords/my_simulator.resource

Where:

The ../../ part is the path 'up' from a test to the project root. E.g., if the test is located in tests\folder\tests.robot
keywords/my_simulator.resource is the path down from the project root to the resource file.

Here is more information in the official User Guide:
2.8.1   Resource files
